# What does it mean when a table is listed with fragmentation?

Tags: sql-server-2014

With this query I can list index fragmentation:

```
SELECT dbschemas.[name] as 'Schema',
dbtables.[name] as 'Table',
dbindexes.[name] as 'Index',
indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
indexstats.page_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
INNER JOIN sys.tables dbtables on dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas dbschemas on dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS dbindexes ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
WHERE indexstats.database_id = DB_ID()
ORDER BY indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent desc
```

But sometimes, it's listed like this:

[image]

What does this mean? is the table fragmented?

And, while I'm here, I would like to ask another question.

I'm using a job to reorganize indexes. All of them are just being reorganized, because this database is running at full speed 24/7 and I can't use rebuild because of locks.

What is the best way to use rebuild\reorganize in this situation? is Hallengren a better solution in this case? if im not mistaken, if the index can't be locked, it will just reorganize it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Dont try to reinvent the wheel as [there is a cost to reinventing it](https://thebertrandfamily.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/).

Use [Ola's maintenance scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) - they are tested well enough and follow best practice. You can even use [LockTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189470.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in Ola's solution.

I would not worry on the fragmentation levels where the page count is less than 5K.

> What is the best way to use rebuild\reorganize in this situation?

Do the index maintenance during less activity or maintenance time.

Comment: Thanks kim. I will use it. but, what about the tables with AVG_fragmentation with null indexes? is this table fragmentation? I never heard it before and I would like to study it a little more.

Comment: Did you check if they are Heaps or not ?

Comment: Yes I checked it. they have some indexes. ( one of them has 6 indexes ). Some of them are being shown below the list with <5% fragmentation. I found A question here, where it said to "create a clustered index to reorganize the HEAP, and then drop it ". but i think it's not the case here.

Comment: Hmmm having indexes doesn't mean it's not a heap though.  You can have indexes on a heap. Kin was specifically asking to see if you have a 'clustered' index on there.  Can you let us know?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition?  That gives you additional options for defragmentation.